# Passing data from Scrapy to Socket

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, scrapy

Currently I have a scrapy which is used to crawl data from websites. I want to send the current data to a connected client it has scraped using a socket.

```
clients = set()
clients_lock = threading.Lock()

host = socket.gethostbyname("") 
port = 10010

def listener(client, address, item):
    print ("Accepted connection from: ", address)
    with clients_lock:
        clients.add(client)
    try:    
        data = client.recv(1024)
        if data == ('0').encode():
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
            client.send(timestamp.encode())
    finally:
        with clients_lock:
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()

def send_to_socket(item):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(3)
    th = []

    client, address = s.accept()
    th.append(Thread(target=listener, args = (client,address, item)).start())
    s.close()
```

The code give below is the scrapy code which calls the function that starts the socket, the current issue is that I am not able to retrieve data from client code real-time. The current code closes client connection every-time it sends a data. Is there any way to continuously send data without closing client connection. If I remove client.remove(client) the code gets stuck and won't run _build_link_item.

_build_link_item runs continuously to generate data from different URL's and I want to send that data it generated to the client.

```
def _build_link_item(response):
    """Builds a LinkItem object for the given response"""
    parser = HTMLParser(response)

    item = LinkItem(
        url=response.url,
        status=response.status,
        content_type=response.headers.get("Content-Type", b"").decode("utf-8") or "",
    )

    print(json.dumps(item.__dict__), flush=True)
    send_to_socket(json.dumps(item.__dict__))
```